# Is there any reason to Object.freeze a function?

Tags: javascript, immutability

I understand the point of recursing over a deep object to do a shallow `Object.freeze` on every child property of it. What is the point of freezing a function object's value? The reference is already frozen because of the shallow freeze at a higher level--is it possible to mutate the function object's value itself?

Example:

```
// Library Function [deepFreeze source](https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze/blob/master/index.js)
function deepFreeze (o) {
  Object.freeze(o); // shallow freeze the top level
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).forEach(function (prop) {
    if o[prop] != null // no point freezing null or undefined
    && (typeof o[prop] === "object" || typeof o[prop] === "function") {
      deepFreeze(o[prop]);
    }
  });
  return o;
};

// Usage
var x = {
  y: [1,2,3],
  z: function(){}
};
deepFreeze(x);
```

Just trying to see if there's something fundamental I don't understand here or if this is just protecting against mutating the function object, eg: `x.z.foo = 3`.

Comment: A function is still an object that you can extend. What's your dilemma?

Comment: A function is also an Object in JS (just one that can be executed). It can be extended with additional properties, like any other Object.

Comment: Functions are objects which you can still add/remove properties to/from. So in general if you want an object completely frozen, you'll want to freeze any functions.

Comment: No, you've pretty much got it. Its kinda pointless, but even more pointless to write code that treats functions differently than other objects. All of this is kinda moot in ES 6 though since we have `Map`s and no longer have to use objects for key:value data structures.

Comment: I guess you mean the function body itself containing the source code. You have no direct access to the body. You can read it via the `toString` method though. `Object.freeze` has no effect on the body of a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript, functions are objects. This I knew.

All of the native properties of the function object (except `prototype`) are already immutable:

```
var x = function(foo){}
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x)
// ["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype"]
x.length; // 1, because there is one argument
x.length = 2;
x.length; // still 1.
```

But you can, of course, add other properties:

```
x.foo = 3;
x.foo; // 3
```

But I think using a function as a data structure is extremely uncommon.

The comment that really resonates with me is Jared's:

> Its kinda pointless, but even more pointless to write code that treats functions differently than other objects.

People can add whatever properties they want to a function object, and in some cases that might be a reasonable solution, but I think it's typically unexpected to store values there. However, writing a library function to treat functions differently than any other object gains nothing.

Conclusion: lock the function object down just like a regular object because why not, and also it closes a corner case where someone might put a value on it.

Comment: Using functions as objects is a common pattern in AngularJS

Comment: In what way, @HubertGrzeskowiak? It's also common to add properties to functions intended to be called as Constructors (with `new`), but this question is, perhaps too implicitly, about data structures.